# Gradle/JavaFX: self-contained application and editable config file?

Tags: java, configuration, gradle, self-contained

I'm using gradle with the [javafx-gradle](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle) plugin to produce a self-contained javafx application using the task "jfxDeploy".

I have the following directory structure:

```
|-- src
|    |-- main
|         |-- java
|         |     \-- Main.java
|         |-- resources
|               \-- database_config.properties
```

I'm loading the database configuration with the *apache-commons-configuration* and use its information to connect to to a database (information = port, ip - normal database stuff):

```
public static DBConnectionParameters getConfigDBConnectionParameters() {
    try {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(getProperty("configIP"));
        String port = getProperty("configPort");
        return new DBConnectionParameters(ip, port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

After creating the self-contained application the build directory contains my program which is now startable using the .exe. The directory structure looks like that:

```
|-- AppName
|    |-- app
|         \-- externalJars.jar
|    |-- runtime\...
|    \-- AppName.exe
|    \-- AppName.ico
```

Starting the program, reading the database configuration and connecting to the database **works fine, but:**
I need to be able to change the *database_config.properties* every now and then. But since I now got my self-contained app, the file is not accessible anymore. 
**So, i need a editable file for configuring my parameters - while at the same time using a self-contained application.**
To prevent misunderstanding: the configuration file does not need read protection. What i need is (and it's perfectly fine) the file just laying in the application folder (or a subdirectory).

I like to keep my applications dynamic - and a little file for fast configuration is perfect for achieving that. How to do it?

Comment: What I've seen is: multiple configuration files. The default comes with your distribution. An installation may add another one, containing a subset overriding the default. A user may have yet another one, overriding default+installation, perhaps in his home directory. And command line parameters may provide yet another level, overriding individually for an execution of your app.

Comment: So you're saying look for a config file in say "./app/configfiles" and if nothing is there, use the built-in config-file? This should be feasible via a simple gradle task that launches after the deploy task i think?

Comment: You define the order the files a read - whatever makes more sense. I think that reading *all* of them - default, installation, user, command line - is the best as definitions in later files can override earlier ones.